# Login error after password change in Salesforce IDe

Tags: eclipse-plugin, salesforce, apex-code

I use Salesforce IDE (standalone).

I had to change my SF password, and from that moment, when I start the IDE, I get a login error, and telling me I need to call from the API: reset password.

I don't understand what needs to be done, as there is no setting in the IDE for password.

Do I need to call reset API in my apexclass?  this seems weird.

Thansk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Force.com project has your outdated password associated to it. You can either delete the project and create a new one (which would require you to specify the new password), or change your password on the current project by right-clicking on the project in the Package Explorer and going to Properties. You should see something similar to the screenshot below, where you can enter your new password and security token, if necessary.

[image: Force.com Properties Window]